# Problem does not follow DCP rules. Sharp ration

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I can't find where the problem in my code is.  Can someone please help me find where the error is?

It shows the following DCP error:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
QuadForm(var1,....
```

The full code is

```py
df = pd.read_excel('dados.xlsx', sheet_name='DWJ')
df.to_csv('dados.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv')

in_sample = df.loc[(df['Data'] >= '2004-01-01') & (df['Data'] < '2009-01-01')]
in_sample = in_sample.drop(columns='TLR')
out_of_sample = df.loc[(df['Data'] >= '2009-01-01') & (df['Data'] < '2014-01-01')]
out_of_sample = out_of_sample.drop(columns='TLR')

mu = in_sample.mean().values
mu[np.isnan(mu)] = 0

Sigma = in_sample.cov().values
Sigma[np.isnan(Sigma)]= 0

n_assets = len(mu)

w = cp.Variable(n_assets)

ret = mu
risk = cp.quad_form(w, Sigma)

lambda_ = cp.Parameter(nonneg=True)

utility = w.T @ ret - (lambda_ / 2)*risk
objective = cp.Maximize(utility)
constraints = [
    w >= 0,
    cp.sum(w) == 1
]
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

lambdas = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
for lam in lambdas:
    lambda_.value = lam
    problem.solve()
    print(f"Para lambda = {lam}, status = {problem.status}, retorno esperado = {ret.T @ w.value}, volatilidade = {np.sqrt(w.value.T @ Sigma @ w.value)}")

w.value

in_sample = in_sample.fillna(0.00)

in_sample2 = in_sample.drop(columns='Data')

retorno_in = in_sample2 @ w.value

print(retorno_in.sum())

out_of_sample = out_of_sample.fillna(0.00)

out_of_sample2 = out_of_sample.drop(columns='Data')

retorno = out_of_sample2 @ w.value
print (retorno.sum()) 

peso = w.value
peso_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['peso','in-sample','out-of-sample'])
peso_df['peso']=peso
peso_df.index=out_of_sample2.columns
peso_df['in-sample'] = retorno_in.sum()
peso_df['out-of-sample'] = retorno.sum()

peso_df.to_excel('resultado_Sharpe_2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Probably your Sigma is not PSD. Check the eigenvalues.